# Spring - Converting property value to upper case?

Tags: spring, properties, code-injection

This question may sound crazy; does spring convert bean property value to upper case value in any means?

```
<bean name="carkBaseEnvironment" abstract="true">
    <property name="environment" value="${env.property}" />
    <property name="tla" value="${app.app}" />
    <property name="applicationId" value="${app.id}" />
</bean>


<bean name='oraEnv' class='a.b.TempClass' parent='carkBaseEnvironment'>
    <property name="system" value="${app.system.oracle}" />
    <property name="resource" value="${database.instance.resource}" />
    <property name="local" value="dd999" />
</bean>
```

It is converting the property "local" value to upper case. unfortunately that is a password.
I don't know what is happening. Please advise.

Comment: my bad it is not spring, we have internal aspects which are intercepting the dat and converting it to uppercase. it took a while for me to understand.